# Modified Cursor 'lags'

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently building a modified cursor for my portfolio-website. Unfortunately, my cursor lags when I try to scroll and move the cursor. However, it works when I remove all the other elements from HTML, CSS, and JavaScript and ONLY have the code concerning my cursor (https://codepen.io/djaisdjasidj/pen/RwNvePZ).

```js
// Cursor modified
var cursor = document.getElementById('cursor');
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var x = e.clientX;
    var y = e.clientY;
    cursor.style.left = x + 'px';
    cursor.style.top = y + 'px';
});

// Cursor HOVER modified - When hovering an element
var cursor = document.getElementById('cursor');
var clickableCursor = document.getElementsByClassName('clickableCursor');

for (var i = 0; i < clickableCursor.length; i++) {
    clickableCursor[i].addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
        cursor.style.height = "80px";
        cursor.style.width = "80px";
        cursor.style.animation = "cursorAnimation 5s linear infinite";
        cursor.style.background = "white";
    });
    clickableCursor[i].addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
        cursor.style.height = "40px";
        cursor.style.width = "40px";
        cursor.style.animation = "none";
        cursor.style.border = "2px solid white";
      cursor.style.background = "none";
    });
}
```

```css
body {
  cursor: none;
}

.container {
  height: 3000px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: orange;
}

#cursor {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 1000000000;
  position: fixed;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  transition: .1s;
  border-radius: 50%;
  pointer-events: none;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition-duration: 100ms;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

#cursor::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 7px;
  width: 7px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}

.clickableCursor {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  background: black;
  padding: 50px
}

.one {
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
}

.two {
  top: 50px;
  right: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="cursor"></div>
  <p class="clickableCursor one"> Hello </p>
</div>
```

CSS for my Cursor:

```
#cursor {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 1000000000;
  position: fixed;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  transition: .1s;
  border-radius: 50%;
  pointer-events: none;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition-duration: 100ms;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
```

My question is - how do I prevent this cursor 'lag' when I have a bigger HTML, CSS, and JavaScript file?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] here on Stack Overflow, not just on an external site. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to do so.

Comment: The lag happens because you use Javascript to update the html element position. It’s also a rather complex element. It might help to use only CSS to change the cursor image. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor

Comment: There is no other way to do it, I need to use Javascript. I've tried to remove the whole cursor-hover effects from my JS-code but it still lags.. @Kokodoko

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and i solved it with this code :
(hope it can help you or other developers)

```js
$(window).ready(function(){

    let mouseX = 0;
    let mouseY = 0;
    let xp = 0;
    let yp = 0;
  
    $(document).mousemove(function(e){
      $(".custom__cursor__inner").css({
        transform: 'translate(' + (e.clientX - 3.25) + 'px, ' + (e.clientY - 3.25) + 'px)'
      });

      mouseX = e.clientX - 10;
      mouseY = e.clientY - 10;
    });
  
    setInterval(function(){
      xp += ((mouseX - xp)/6);
      yp += ((mouseY - yp)/6);
      $(".custom__cursor__outer").css({transform: 'translateX('+ (xp - 15) +'px) translateY('+ (yp - 15) +'px)'} );
    }, 10);
})
```

```css
*{
    cursor: none;
}

.custom__cursor__inner{
    height: 7.5px;
    width: 7.5px;
    position: fixed;
    transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    background-color: #F7D883;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: height .3s cubic-bezier(0.46,0.03,0.52,0.96), width .3s cubic-bezier(0.46,0.03,0.52,0.96);
    z-index: 5000;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.custom__cursor__outer{
    height: 50px;
    width:  50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #0F1928;
    background-color: transparent;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 5000;
    transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 0.4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="custom__cursor__outer">
</div>
<div class="custom__cursor__inner">
</div>
```

Comment: Nice share! Thanks. Can't seem to figure our how to contain it within a div. I have a gallery of images, and want a custom hover icon ( basically a svg text saying: 'click to open' ), but when the mouse leaves the image, it should stay contained in the image div ( and fade out after 3 sec ).

Comment: You're welcome. I'm not sure to understand exactly what you are trying to do but create a snippet and maybe we can help you out.

Answer (score 1):

The lag happens because you are using a transition to move the cursor to the current mouse location, explicitly stating that it should be lagging behind 100ms.

You should only apply the CSS transition on the elements and attributes that you want to animate, but not the *location* of the cursor.

Use the `transition-property` rule to define which attributes should be "transitioned" or use the transition shorthand syntax to explicitly specify the attribute names like @Tyler Roper does in his comment.

Comment: Yes, when I removed the transition on #cursor, the 'lag' disappeared.. But is there a solution for using transition-duration: 100ms; on my cursor without lagging?

Comment: @Hejha What is the transition meant to do? You can specify properties for which the transition should apply by changing `transition: .1s` to `transition: color .1s, background-color .1s` etc.

Comment: When I hover on the black divs, I want the cursor to get bigger, but without the transition the cursor will not appear smooth @TylerRoper